# Replace is producing weird answers in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace

i am using dictionary key value pair to replace some string.

```
dict= {'MAA':'MADRAS', 'MAD':'MADRID'}
```

now using `.replace()`, it replaces MAA to MADRAS but MAD of MADRAS is again replaced by MARDRID. This is giving me wrong output and i have 8000+ key value pairs so my output is getting very weird. Is there any way to correct it.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

---

I am using the below code:

```
#creating dict from dataframe with 8k+ key value pairs.. 
iata_dict = dict(zip(df7.CityCode, df7.CityName))
for x,y in iata_dict.items():
    df6["Itinerary"] = df6["Itinerary"].str.replace(x, y)
```

---

this is a column in my data frame Itinerary which is having data like-

```
BRISBANE-AKL-SCL-LIM/CIX-LIM/LAX/BNE
PER-HKG/HND/PVG-HKG/PER
PER/JNB/PER
PER-DXB/ALA-TSE/LHR-DXB/PER
BNE/LST/MEL-CHC/IVC/CHC/BNE
ANF/SCL-ATL/SLC-LAX-SYD/BNE
MAA-BOM/HYD/MAA
MEL/SIN/MEL
PER-SYD/SFO/MSO/SLC-LAX-BNE/PER
```

Comment: How are you replacing the data. Can you show the code

Comment: without watching the code i only can say that you should replace MAD first and then MAA. if you want to replace it in both ways you need to write new/better REGEX and not using `replace()` with charsequence.

Comment: Hi,  i am using the below code:                                                       iata_dict = dict(zip(df7.CityCode, df7.CityName))   #creating dict from dataframe with 8k+ key value pairs..

for x,y in iata_dict.items():
    df6["Itinerary"] = df6["Itinerary"].str.replace(x, y)

Comment: Please include a minimal example of the DataFrame - like `df6.head(7)`. and the expected result for that example. --- [mcve]

Comment: `@wwii` this is a column of my dataframe- `BNE-AKL-SCL-LIM/CIX-LIM/LAX/BNE
PER-HKG/HND/PVG-HKG/PER
PER/JNB/PER
PER-DXB/ALA-TSE/LHR-DXB/PER
BNE/LST/MEL-CHC/IVC/CHC/BNE
ANF/SCL-ATL/SLC-LAX-SYD/BNE
MAA-BOM/HYD/MAA
MEL/SIN/MEL`
i am replacing these with `{'MAA':'Madras','MAD':'MADRID','SYD':'SYDNEY',....... upto 8K key value pairs}`. `MAA` should give me `MADRAS` but i am getting `MADRIDRAS`, `MAD` is again getting replaced by 'MADRID'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's need to be optimized, but this works:

```
import re
di= {'MAA':'MADRAS', 'MAD':'MADRID'}
st = ['BRISBANE-AKL-SCL-LIM/CIX-LIM/LAX/BNE',
'PER-HKG/HND/PVG-HKG/PER',
'PER/JNB/PER',
'PER-DXB/ALA-TSE/LHR-DXB/PER',
'BNE/LST/MEL-CHC/IVC/CHC/BNE',
'ANF/SCL-ATL/SLC-LAX-SYD/BNE',
'MAA-BOM/HYD/MAA',
'MEL/SIN/MEL',
'PER-SYD/SFO/MSO/SLC-LAX-BNE/PER']
for s in st:
    for d in di.keys():
        r = re.compile('(?![A-Z])*' + d + '(?![A-Z])*')
        s = re.sub(r, di[d],s)
    print(s)
```

This regular expression checks for word which we replace is not surrounded by another words or letters. Other surrounding symbols is fine.
If you want to optimize this code you can compile expressions before strings loop.

Here is output:

```
BRISBANE-AKL-SCL-LIM/CIX-LIM/LAX/BNE
PER-HKG/HND/PVG-HKG/PER
PER/JNB/PER
PER-DXB/ALA-TSE/LHR-DXB/PER
BNE/LST/MEL-CHC/IVC/CHC/BNE
ANF/SCL-ATL/SLC-LAX-SYD/BNE
MADRAS-BOM/HYD/MADRAS
MEL/SIN/MEL
PER-SYD/SFO/MSO/SLC-LAX-BNE/PER
```

Comment: Hi @CrazyElf, it is giving me `MADRIDRAS` for `MAA` instead of `MADRAS`.

Comment: It's strange. I'v got this output:

BRISBANE-AKL-SCL-LIM/CIX-LIM/LAX/BNE
PER-HKG/HND/PVG-HKG/PER
PER/JNB/PER
PER-DXB/ALA-TSE/LHR-DXB/PER
BNE/LST/MEL-CHC/IVC/CHC/BNE
ANF/SCL-ATL/SLC-LAX-SYD/BNE
MADRAS-BOM/HYD/MADRAS
MEL/SIN/MEL
PER-SYD/SFO/MSO/SLC-LAX-BNE/PER

Comment: Which version of Python do you use? May be it's a key. Mine is 3.6

Comment: Hi @CrazyElf, i know its strange, mine python is 3.6 as well, and my output is- BRISBANE-AKL-SCL-LIM/CIX-LIM/LAX/BNE
PER-HKG/HND/PVG-HKG/PER
PER/JNB/PER
PER-DXB/ALA-TSE/LHR-DXB/PER
BNE/LST/MEL-CHC/IVC/CHC/BNE
ANF/SCL-ATL/SLC-LAX-SYD/BNE
`MADRIDRAS-BOM/HYD/MADRIDRAS`
MEL/SIN/MEL
PER-SYD/SFO/MSO/SLC-LAX-BNE/PER

Comment: Hi @CrazyElf, i want to get the output values in a dataframe. Instead of `print(s)`, i want it to return in `df['Itinerary']`. I am not able to get this thing. Thanks.

Comment: You need to define your function for string modification and use .map() to apply this function to column of dataframe. Sorry, have no time now to explain more.